# blender object doesnt scale, new vertices appear instead

Tags: vertices, transforms, extrude, knife-tool

Im new to blender and this happens when I try to scale extrude etc. The object itself doesnt transform and new vertices appear istead.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, it's not clear, could you please show what you're doing step bu step?

Comment: Okay, so first, I was trying to stretch the edge so I used "select box" to select the two vertices. And I pressed S with X to stretch it sideways. However, unlike other parts of the object(like screenshot number 2), the face would not stretch with the vertices. The face would just remain and two new vertices would come out of nowhere.

Comment: so these vertices were already here and they were overlapping some existing ones, maybe first select all and press M > Merge by Distance

Comment: thank you so much!! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have created overlapping vertices by accident. Select all, press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, then scale again.

Answer (score 0):

Point has no dimensions, therefore, scaling operator does not work, and extrude generates an edge and point from the existent point.

Have you tried to switch to edge or face before apply scale operation?

Comment: Cant I select points of an object and scale them? The second photo works fine